# Why do my node.js applications on heroku say 'secure' but my rails app say 'not secure'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, security, heroku

I have been using heroku to deploy my rails and node.js applications but I have noticed that my node.js applications say secure in green text on the top left near the url but my rails apps say not secure. These applications are often similar applications in concept and involve users, tokens, sql injection prevention, regex to control inputs, hashing of sensitive data, the standard create, read, update and deleting of data, so there is really not a big difference between my not secure and secure applications on the root level other then language difference.

What is the criteria that makes it secure, and how can I make my rails apps secure?

Comment: Are you using custom domains for both the apps? You are on free tier or paid?

Comment: I'm using the free tier for all my applications